# Can I write a service that uses blazor webassembly server session and use this session object in the client side

Tags: asp.net-core, session, blazor-webassembly, hosted

I have a blazor web assembly asp.net core hosted app, I need a session storage for my client side app that I use in a service to get and set jwt tokens.

So I have a service "AuthenticationStateProvider" that uses server session for store/retrieve user's jwt tokens.

Since I didn't find any solution to access the browser from a client side service, I had to use session state from the server.

Is this a good solution, and is it work as I expect, without problems in a production website, and is secure?

Comment: See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#aspnet-core-protected-browser-storage

Comment: so storing any data from blazor webassembly client in the server session is possible and works as expected? and the data is different for each user?

Comment: In a web assembly application there is no server session.  There's a SPA session in the WASM session running on the browser.  Protected storage will preserve data across SPA sessions.

Comment: I call an Api service to set/get user's token (ISession: HttpContext.Session in the api server) So this is wrong and will not work?

Comment: How can a client get a stored JWT token securely on the API server?  It needs the token to verify the user.

Comment: Those session values should be stored in cookies (server sends set-cookie header), but they are probably set as http-only.  You can check them from the browser's dev tools.  The browser will send them along with any request to the domain they are set from.  They are set "http-only" to protect them against attacks such as XSS.